# Meromorphic functions and the homotopy principle? What gives?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, homotopy-theory

I've been reading about integral transforms (Mellin transform and Fourier transform) and was wondering if there was a promising way to map the prime numbers into a different region? What if you could squash all the primes into a bounded, compact space, which might be easier to manage than having them all run off to infinity, and become more sparse as they go.

Edit 3/1/2020:

I think I'm looking for the notion of a continuous compactification of a meromorphic function. Specifically, is there a way to "track," so to speak the location of values of a meromorphic function undergoing "deformation." I'm thinking of something like a homotopy, but is there anything like that in complex analysis, or just in topology?

I mention primes because there is a well-known function that encodes rich information about the primes. Maybe if such a "complex homotopic map" was found, then progress could be made solving the Riemann Hypothesis. After a quick online search, I think this notion already exists! (https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~forstneric/papers/2003%20Contemp.%20Math.pdf)

[Meromorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function)

[Extending domain of a meromorphic function from non-compact to compact domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86525/extending-domain-of-a-meromorphic-function-from-non-compact-to-compact-domain)

Can anyone summarize (in a few sentences) the paper to I linked in parentheses to help me (and possibly others) understand the basics of such a homotopic map in the field of complex analysis?

Here's my attempt: "The homotopy principle for meromorphic functions is essentially a way to smoothly encode and transition geometrical and/or analytical information about a meromorphic function, assuming that there are no topological obstructions."

Comment: I don't know of anything quite like what you describe.  Primes in $\mathbb N$ are interesting because of their algebraic properties, so it would seem the only useful transforms would have to preserve them mostly.  One possibility is to embed them in a larger setting, like the Gaussian integers.  Another idea is to change the metric, as we do with $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: @hardmath I'll try to make it clearer...no way to map primes to the unit interval?

Comment: We can map all the positive integers into the "unit interval", for example by taking $f(n) = 1/n$.  This of course maps the subset of positive *prime* integers into the unit interval.  But I don't see this making the analysis of prime numbers easier.

Comment: How does changing the metric, such as with $p-$adic numbers, make the analysis of prime numbers easier?

Comment: To give the obvious answer... someone CAN summarize the main points of the linked paper: the author, who does so in the first three pages.

Comment: @JohnHughes To give a rebuttal, I don't understand it enough and I would like a several sentence distillation of those three pages. Furthermore, I would like someone to verify my attempt at the summary.

Comment: So if you didn't understand it when lots of background and related work are carefully explained, what additional insight do you expect to get from a necessarily-lossy short summary? I personally believe that right thing to do, when you don't understand the introduction to a paper, is to go learn the material necessary to understand it. There is no royal road to mathematics, much to my dismay.

Comment: I’m not looking for you’re so called “royal road” and plan to finish reading the paper in the coming months. I am merely asking for a summary, so that I can retroactively verify my understanding of the matter and make cross-correlations to update my understanding.